How to return string array in GLibSharp SignalArgs
I'm using GStreamer 1.24.2 and I'm trying to utilize the splitmuxsrc to concatenate some mp4 files together. I have a list of specific files, so I believe I need to use the format-location signal. Also, this is all happening in C# with GStreamer-Sharp.
Here is my signal handler:
private void HandleFormatLocation(
    object o,
    SignalArgs args)
{
    if (!RecordingFiles.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    var files = RecordingFiles.OrderBy(p => p.StartDate)
        .ToList()
        .Select(p => p.Filename)
        .Select(p => p.Replace("\\", "\\\\"))
        .ToArray();

    Logger.LogWarning("Getting files: {files}", files.JoinString(", "));

    var value = new Value(files);
    args.RetVal = value;
}

Here is corresponding logging output:
[15:21:08 WRN] Getting files: D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000041.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000042.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000043.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000044.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000045.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000046.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000047.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000048.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000049.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000050.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000051.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000052.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000053.mp4, D:/VideoRecording/Ubiquiti/video0000054.mp4
[15:21:08 ERR] MESSAGE: Pipeline error for view recording files:
Could not open resource for reading.
../gst/multifile/gstsplitmuxsrc.c(506): gst_splitmux_part_bus_handler (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSplitMuxSrc:concat:
Failed to prepare first file part ☺ for playback

The filenames I'm logging appear to be correct, but it seems once they get sent over to GStreamer, the first file is a smiley face. So, clearly something weird is happening. I'm suspecting it's in code from https://github.com/GLibSharp/GtkSharp. I'm unsure why GStreamer uses this library. Seems like maybe it's a fork of https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp.
I have asked about this on GStreamer chat and in GStreamer discourse and haven't received any help. I've also been scouring the internet looking for an example of returning string[] on SignalArgs to no avail.
It should also be noted that I've tried to do this at the end of the handler:
var temp = value.Val;

Which results in:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.Exception: Unknown type GStrv
   at GLib.Value.ToBoxed()
   at GLib.Value.get_Val()

I don't know if that's related, but it does make me wonder if this project supports returning a string[]. Any idea what I could do?
